# How to do Sql IN operator with RethinkDb and C#

Tags: c#, rethinkdb

Does anyone know how to do the following example in c#. This is taken from the javascript examples on the RethinkDb website. I've tried a lot of things and cant get it to work in c#. What I really want is to do it with a variable number of parameters.
I'm using the RethinkDb.Driver library.

In SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE name IN ('Peter', 'John')
```

In javascript

```
r.table("users").filter(
  function (doc) {
    return r.expr(["Peter","John"])
            .contains(doc("name"));
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

```
R.Table("users").Filter(a =>
{
    R.Expr(new string[]{"Peter","John"}).Contains(a.Bracket("name"))
})
```

Comment: Not sure why this question was closed - it was the exact question I had and the answer I was looking for.